# JavaScript Table Lookup in a PDF

Tags: javascript, arrays, pdf

I'm using JavaScript to calculate values in a fillable PDF file.  I would like to embed a price chart to automate looking up values (reduce human error).  Here is an example chart:

```
Carpet Install Price Chart                  
        Price Per Square Foot           
Sq Ft   1 Room  2 Rooms 3 Rooms 4 Rooms 5 Rooms
1000    0.1500  0.1650  0.1931  0.2259  0.2643
1500    0.1450  0.1595  0.1866  0.2183  0.2555
2000    0.1400  0.1540  0.1786  0.2072  0.2404
2500    0.1350  0.1485  0.1723  0.1998  0.2318
3000    0.1300  0.1430  0.1645  0.1891  0.2175
3500    0.1250  0.1375  0.1581  0.1818  0.2091
4000    0.1200  0.1320  0.1505  0.1715  0.1956
4500    0.1150  0.1265  0.1442  0.1644  0.1874
5000    0.1100  0.1210  0.1367  0.1545  0.1746
5500    0.1050  0.1155  0.1305  0.1475  0.1667
6000    0.1000  0.1100  0.1243  0.1405  0.1587
6500    0.0950  0.1045  0.1181  0.1334  0.1508
7000    0.0900  0.0990  0.1119  0.1264  0.1428
```

The document-level JavaScript function input parameters would be two values, total square feet and number of rooms.  The function would round to the nearest square foot value in the first column (to find the appropriate row), then lookup the return value in the table based on the given number of rooms.

I've seen examples where there are only two columns of data, but no examples with many columns of data.

Any advice on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before. Set up the table as a JSON object and have it load with the document level script then reference it from your calculated fields.